# Calling a string in another sub from that it was before

Tags: vb.net, string, path

I have a sub called `ReadingText` and it has inside a string named *tempstr*..I need to call tempstr in another Sub called `SaveToolStripMenuItem`
The two Subs are in the same Class..
The codes are bellow:

```
Private Sub ReadingText(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim arguments As String = Command()
    If arguments = String.Empty Then
        RichTextBox1.Text += vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    Else
        Dim tempstr As String = arguments.Replace("""", "")
        Me.Text = tempstr & " - Text"
        Dim SR As New System.IO.StreamReader(tempstr)
        RichTextBox1.Text = SR.ReadToEnd
        Try
            SR.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            RichTextBox1.Text += ex.ToString
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

the above Sub runs when the program starts and it replaces `RichTextBox1.text` with **tempstr** which is the path of the .txt file I have dropped on my .exe program in order to read the context of it..

```
 Private Sub SaveToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim file As StreamWriter
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(filePath) Then
        file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(filePath, True)
        file.WriteLine(RichTextBox1.Text)
    ElseIf (SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK)
        file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, True)
        file.WriteLine(RichTextBox1.Text)
        file.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

This Sub run when the user clicks on Save which is an item in a ToolStrip..This Sub checks if tempstr exists..If it exists it saves the `RichTextBox1.Text` in the tempstr path.. But it doesn't recognize the tempstr,because it is located in another Sub..
What should I do?

Comment: you can declare tempStr outside the Sub Method so the other Sub Method can access the variable or you can use a `property`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read [this thread by MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx) carefully, this is regarding the Scoping of variables and methods. In your case both the methods are comes under the same class, so you need to define(declare) the `tempstr` variable with global scope to the class.if you donot want to access the value out side the class, then No need to make it shared, since the shared variables have application scope.

```
Public Class your ClassName
Dim tempstr As String '<- Global declaration
Private Sub ReadingText(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
' Your code 
End Sub
 Private Sub SaveToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveToolStripMenuItem.Click
'Your code
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Mark tempstr as shared global resource.

```
class Test{
...
Shared tempstr as String=String.Empty
...
}
```

Hope this helps.